# Filter without cluster point, then the clopen members have empty intersection

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, filters

Consider a topological space $(X,\tau)$ and a filter $F$ on $X$ with no cluster point. The set $C$ of all clopen members of $F$ has the finite intersection property. Why has the intersection $\bigcap_{x \in C} x$ to be empty?

I cannot find a way to show that the fact, that the intersection is not-empty implies that every element of the filter $N$ of neighbourhoods of $x$, has a non-empty intersection with every element of $F$.

If this would be the case, then $N \cup F$ would yield a subbasis for a convergent filter: a contradiction to the fact, that $F$ has no cluster point.

---

**EDIT**

It seems, that I generalized the problem too much. Take a look at the following proof of Herrlich's *Axiom of Choice* (Theorem 4.92 about equivalence of Ascoli Theorem w.r.t. ultrafilter=compactness and PIT = Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem):

[image]

In $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$, the fact, that $P=\mathfrak{2}^I$ is not compact w.r.t. the open covering property leads to a filter $F$ with no cluster point.

What am I missing?

Comment: I wanted to have a look at [the paper](http://ftp.math.uni-rostock.de/pub/MetaFiles/herrlich-51.html) referenced in the proof. (To see whether the proof is formulated in this paper in the same way.) But for some reason [the download link](ftp://ftp.math.uni-rostock.de/pub/romako/heft51/herrlich.ps.Z) does not work for me. EDIT: But it worked from here: http://www.math.uni-rostock.de/cgi-bin/publikationen/romako.pl?51

Comment: How about the fact that Cantor Cubes are totally disconnected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1603329/2) was already [answered by Henno Brandsma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603329/filter-without-cluster-point-then-the-clopen-members-have-empty-intersection/1603689#1603689). I will try to respond to the [new version](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1603329/5) of your question.

The key here is probably the fact that $2^I$ is [zero-dimensional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-dimensional_space). I.e., it has a base consisting of clopen sets. So let us check whether the claim holds in such spaces.

Suppose that $\mathcal F\subseteq \mathcal P(Z)$ is a filter and $Z$ is a zero-dimensional space. Suppose that $\mathcal F$ has no cluster point, meaning that $$\bigcap_{F\in\mathcal F}\overline F=\emptyset.$$

Now let $z\in Z$. Since $z$ is not a cluster point of $\mathcal F$, there exists and $F\in\mathcal F$ such that $z\notin\overline F$. Then 
there exists a (basic) clopen neighborhood $U$ of the point $z$ 
$$U\cap F=\emptyset.$$
From this we get that $Z\setminus U\supseteq F$ and
$$Z\setminus U\in\mathcal F.$$
So we found a clopen set in the filter $\mathcal F$ which does not contain the point $z$. This implies that
$$z\notin\bigcap\{A\in\mathcal F; A\text{ is clopen}\}.$$

Since this is true for every $z\in Z$, we get that
$$\bigcap\{A\in\mathcal F; A\text{ is clopen}\}=\emptyset.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how do you prove $2^I$ is zero dimensional?

Comment: @el_tenedor Just notice that the sets from standard basis (for the product topology) are clopen.

Comment: Or even simpler: Start with the fact that the sets from the subbasis are clopen. (A set from the subbasis consists from all points such that $i$-th coordinate is prescribed, where $i\in I$ is some fixed index. It is relatively easy to see that these sets are clopen.) Use this fact to deduce that the basic sets are clopen, too. (Any basic set is an intersection of finitely many sets from the subbasis.)

Comment: Thanks again! Every subbasis element is open by definition and has an open complement, since $2$ is discrete. The finite intersection property of clopen sets then implies that the basis sets again are clopen. Correct?

Comment: That sound fine to me.

Answer (score 5):

Why would this be true, without further assumptions? Take a filter on the reals (usual topology) without a cluster point (which can be done as the reals are not compact). The only clopen member of any filter is $\mathbb{R}$ itself, by connectedness, and this has non-empty intersection...

Comment: To be even more specific, one can take the filter consisting of all subsets of $\Bbb R$ that contain a ray of the form $(x,\to)$ for some $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thank you both for your answers. Still, I am not sure which assumptions I am missing. I updated my post describing where my apparently wrong statement originated.